# Android Studio gets stucked in Starting screen?

Tags: android, android-studio

Starting Screen showing "powered by IntelliJ Platform" appears and just stays on the screen.
I have no idea what to do with it.
Eclipse worked fine on my previous PC

Comment: You probably need to do a re-install.

Comment: That didn't help. 
it takes a lot of time (approx 30 min.) to open.
Please help!!